# Problem while running Angular project project on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run my Angular project on AWS ec2 in production, it automatically gets changed to the host AWS IP address. I am unable to run my service. Has anyone faced this issue previously? Please help

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o98MI.png)

Comment: It seems that Angular calls some API & it use IP Address to connect with that API? And your problem is that instead of connecting by URL it uses IP Address. Please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: have you hosted both API & Angular on same EC2 Instance? Also, please shared server name as well.

Comment: Yes, We have hosted both servers on the same instance. and which server name do you asking for?

Comment: server name means..it is IIS, apache etc.

Comment: Ohh, we are not using any ISS or Apache till now. simply we using node for executing our code.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to run the environment in the EC2, 
Create a production build and deploy the code in the AWS >> Instance >> /var/www/html folder.

> Command to build production: ng build --prod --aot

Comment: Could you please elaborate it step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout the public URL of your EC2 Instance. It should be something like below:

```
http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Now, in your Angular code, you must be having a base URL of the API. You should use the base URL of your API something like below:

API Base URL: `http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com/API-Application`

This way, there won't be any IP conversion automatically.

Comment: this is also not working for me.
set base URL like - http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
my API calling like http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/api/user

Comment: http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/api/user <= This is completely wrong URL made by your APP. How can you expect to work?